# Display date in a list conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm working on small React project where I'm using data provided by a flight information API. Everything is working according to plan so far. I can display all array items in a list. Now I'm trying to implement a feature that displays date on a separate row in the list. I only want to display a date one time for one or more items with the same date.

Down below in the condition I'm using the variable *displayDate*. Basically just to be able to turn the date on/off for the moment and to test some logic. What I'm trying to figure now is what logic I need to be able to evaluate the if statement to either true or false. There has to be some sort of comparison between the current date and the next date in the array.

Each object in the array has a property called scheduleDate formatted as "2020-07-06".

Any ideas how I can solve this?

```
<Flights>
                {resolvedData &&
                  resolvedData.flights
                    .filter((item) => item.flightName === item.mainFlight)
                    .map((item, index) => {
                      if (displayDate) {
                        return (
                          <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
                            <Date date={item.scheduleDate} />
                            <Flight flight={item} />
                          </React.Fragment>
                        );
                      } else {
                        return <Flight key={item.id} flight={item} />;
                      }
                    })}
</Flights>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the scheduleDate is different than the previous

```
  const renderTable = () => {
    let currentDate = null;
    return data.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.scheduleDate !== currentDate) {
        currentDate = item.scheduleDate;
        return (
          <>
            <Date/>
            <Flight/>
          </>
        );
      } else {
        return <Flight/>;
      }
    });
  };

  <Flights>{renderTable()}</Flights>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! Would it be possible to have this code inline in the return statement? I'm just curious. When you render the list separately in a function like this, is there a specific name for this pattern in React?